# Got BSOD with USBXHCI.SYS

Tags: windows-10, bsod, analysis

It said Bad_pool_caller

here is the dump file

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0z47lWdEdGPR1JXR1Z5WFpEN2s/view?usp=sharing

All my drivers are up-to-date and I didn't connect any external device. Machine was running fine for 2 weeks and now this error. First time I got this error.

The name tells me it has something to do with USB. But what exactly caused this error?

My hardware is fine as I had tested my hardware by memtest and chkdisk.

Comment: "Activate Driver Verifier with memory pool options enabled, to obtain more information about these errors and to locate the faulting driver." so run verifier.exe and activate the memory pool options or all 3rd party drivers. when you get a new BSOD, disable driver verifier and upload the new dump

Comment: have you done what I told you? I can only help you with the driver verifier enabled dumps.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I will if I get BSOD again :)